# Converting a TeX document to SE markdown?

Tags: conversion

Portions of my masters thesis work, which was never published officially, could be pretty easily adapted to a *very* comprehensively answer to a question on Programmers about [Particle Swarm Optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/308761/52929).

However, I <s>foolishly</s> wisely<sup>1</sup> chose to write it in LaTeX which means I cannot just copy/paste it into the "Answer" text box there, at least (I could copy... the entire document I guess and tell people to use TeX to read it?).

The main concerns I have relate to the mathematical notation and references. Text/headings could be pretty straightforward to modify into markdown syntax.

Something like:

```
\begin{align*}  \labeltarget{eq:opproblem}
    &\operatorname{Minimize}& & F_p(\bar{x})  \quad & &p=1,\dots,l & &\text{\nameref{sec:objectivefunction}}\\
    &\operatorname{Subject\;To} & &g_j(\bar{x}) \leq 0, \quad & &j= 1,\dots,m & &\text{\nameref{sec:inequalityconstraints}} \\
    &&&h_k(\bar{x}) = 0, \quad & &k= 1, \dots,p  & &\text{\nameref{sec:equalityconstraints}} \\
    &&&x_{low,i} \le x_{i} \le x_{up,i}, \quad & &i = 1, \dots,n  & &\text{\nameref{sec:sideconstraints}}   
\end{align*}
```

Would be great to auto convert via [insert magical process I don't know]. I could take screenshots of them, I guess...

There are also a lot of pieces like:

```
    \noindent with $\bar{x}$ representing  \hyperref[sec:designvariables]{design variables} for the optimization problem \cite{vanderplaats}.
```

Which would be.. tedious at best to go through and change.

Is there any straightforward way to minimize the tediousness of converting a TeX document to SE markdown syntax?

---

<sub>1: My advisor also required a Word document during the process (???) and the amount of times I've tried to convert from TeX is making me sick. Fortunately it's more fun than going backwards!</sub>

Comment: Have you considered Pandoc?

Comment: Really not a question at 'our' end