# How can I convert LaTeX text to a format suitable for a StackExchange answer?

Tags: conversion

I have written an answer in LaTeX for a question asked in cstheory.stackexchange. I would like to copy it into an actual answer to the original question. How can I do it?

The main problem is that the LaTeX contains theorems (definitions, lemmas etc.) and I want them to look good in the answer rather than just:

> \begin{lemma} ... \end{lemma}

Comment: Which SE site? Some have mathJax enabled, in which case most TeX formatting can be pasted straight in.  Other than that, I find it usually pretty easy to convert simple TeX to markdown by hand, but if you want an automated solution, [pandoc can do it](http://blog.philippklaus.de/2010/11/use-pandoc-to-convert-latex-to-markdown/).  EDIT: this question is [pretty much a duplicate](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290088/converting-a-tex-document-to-se-markdown?rq=1), but the other question was never answered.

Comment: what do you mean by look good?

Comment: @touhami I mean e.g. that lemmas have a heading, and are not surrounded by "\begin...\end" tags.

Comment: If i understand you have to compile your code and insert the output as `screenshot`

Comment: Isn't this off-topic?

Comment: I would agree with @touhami and just use a **screenshot**.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about using another stackexchange page and is solved by comments.